# What are the abbreviations in Jastrow?

Tags: acronyms, dictionary

I was looking at [Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A0%D6%B0%D7%A6%D6%B7%D7%97.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and there were several English abbreviations related to the definition or word structure that I didn't recognize.  I looked through [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_List_of_Abbreviations?lang=bi) and many of the abbreviations are there but many are not.

First - these: Pa. Af. Ithpe.
I looked in the Sefaria MongoDB dump and these are in a field called "verbal_stem" - but I'm not sure what that means.  It seems they are related to the verb binyan, but I'm not sure each one - eg, what is Af.?  There are other forms that I've seen I don't recognize.

A little further down (word: נֶצַח) it says: "wherever the Biblical text has the words netsaḥ, selah, or vaʿed, it means &c."  What is that "&c."?

Further is: "נַצְחָא m. (preced. wds.)"  What is the wds.?

I could go on. I would appreciate answers to these specific examples but I would really like some pointers or links that can explain it generally for all the examples I didn't list here.

Comment: [Start here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38236&st=&pgnum=14)

Comment: Ithpe.  Ithpeel.  Sefaria Jastrow list of abbreviations

&c.  etc. = et cetera (this is its meaning elsewhwhere. I don't understand its use in context here.)

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @DoubleAA Inasmuch as Jastrow is a dictionary of the Talmuds and Targumin, why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @Loewian Inasmuch as Jastrow is a dictionary of Talmudic and Targumic (?) Aramaic, why should it be?

Comment: This is a question aiming to better understand a tool used by many to understand Jewish texts - it feels on topic to me and can be helpful to many

Comment: Further elaborating on &c being etc. Note the ampersand is actually the Latin for 'and' - 'et' run together.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons, well, it was one, originally, although many modern punchcutters' ampersands don't specifically resemble "et"

Comment: @Yehosef  - 
Et cetera, abbreviated to etc., etc, &c., or &c, is a Latin expression that is used in English to mean "and other similar things", or "and so forth". [Wikipedia]

 "wds."** = "words". Meaning, in your example of נצחא, there are always words that precede this word נצחא - ex. כליל ריש דנצחא = the crown of the chief of victor. 

"AF." = variant spelling of "ad" - assimilated before f (as in affiliate, affirm ).  [Concise Oxford English Dictionary]  = it's a word that precedes other connected words.

Answer (score 3):

The first three you listed are giving the Aramaic *binyan* of the example words, as you've already discovered in the "verbal_stem" reference you found. They say that the three words belong to *pa'el*, *af'el* and *itp'il*, respectively.

See Rabbi Yitzhak Frank's Aramaic grammar for [all of those](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=My4YBfzqOHQC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18) and a readable description of the rest of the language.